# How to get desired output using joins in multiple columns in MySQL/iReport?

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

I performed a query in MySQL like -

```
SELECT  
p.patient_id, p.name, pt.testresult, pt.reffby, t.testname , rf.refrange  
FROM patient AS p  
LEFT JOIN patienttest pt ON p.patient_id = pt.patient_id  
LEFT JOIN test t ON pt.testcode = t.testcode  
LEFT JOIN referencerange rf ON t.test_id = rf.test_id  
WHERE p.patient_id = 10  
AND pt.parent_id = 2 ;
```

and I got result like this -

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+  
| patient_id | name       | testresult | reffby | testname  | refrange            |  
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+ 
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | A:G RATIO | 15-20 for children  |
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | A:G RATIO | 30-60 for adults    |
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | A:G RATIO | 100 - 200 for women |
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | ALBUMIN   | 20-30 for men       |
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | ALBUMIN   | 30-60 for adults    |
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | ALBUMIN   | 100 - 200 for women |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
```

But I do not want repeated values in a column(unique values in column to show this in my report) i.e. like this format -

```
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
| patient_id | name       | testresult | reffby | testname  | refrange            |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
|         10 | Rex Desuza | -ve        | self   | A:G RATIO | 15-20 for children  |
|            |            |            |        |           | 30-60 for adults    |
|            |            |            |        |           | 100 - 200 for women |
|            |            | -ve        |        | ALBUMIN   | 20-30 for men       |
|            |            |            |        |           | 30-60 for adults    |
|            |            |            |        |           | 100 - 200 for women |
+------------+------------+------------+--------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I have to show this result in above format. Please tell me how to do that?

If not possible in server then please tell me how to achieve this format through *iReport*?

If I uncheck the check box "Print Repeated values" property of a text field then testresult "-ve" is not shown for "ALBUMIN" test as it is same as "A:G Ratio" testresult. And I want to show testresult for both tests even if they are same. Please brief me how to achieve that?

Comment: why won.t you do it on application level? it can still be done on the server but you need too much solution for this.

Comment: I agree with @JW., this seems like a job for the application, not the database server.

Comment: @user2185080 What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

In Ireport you can do it very easily, you just have to uncheck the "Print Repeated Values" check box property of a text field.

Comment: If I uncheck the check box "Print Repeated values" property of a text field then testresult "-ve" is not shown for "ALBUMIN" test as it is same as "A:G Ratio" testresult. And I want to show testresult for both tests even if they are same. Please brief me how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat common requirement. [This post](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/535420/suppress-repeated-columns) shows something very similar.

The key idea is this:

1. Create a group on `patient_id`
2. Create a group called `result_and_name` in iReport (not in SQL) on `testresult` + `testname`.
3. Do not show header or footer for either group.
4. Show all field values when `$V{patient_id_COUNT} == 1`.
5. Show only `refrange` otherwise, except:
6. Show the fields `testresult`, `testname`, and `refrange` when `$V{result_and_name_COUNT} == 1`

Lines 4, 5, and 6 are done using Print When Expressions.

Caveat: Your query does not show ordering, but ordering is required for this to make sense.